# Django function based view pagination not working

Tags: python, django

I am having problems with my pagination, The number of pages i put in place (5) is not working.  UnorderedObjectListWarning: Pagination may yield inconsistent results with an unordered object_list:  QuerySet.

How can i change it to a class based view.

```
def post(request, category_slug):
        categories = Category.objects.all()
        post  = Post.objects.all()

        if category_slug:
            category = get_object_or_404(Category, slug=category_slug)
            posts = post.filter(category=category).order_by('-id')

            page = request.GET.get('page', 1)

            paginator = Paginator(posts, 6)
            try:
                users = paginator.page(page)
            except PageNotAnInteger:
                users = paginator.page(1)
            except EmptyPage:
                users = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)
                print(users)

        context = {

            'page_obj': users,
        }




                <nav aria-label="Page navigation example">
                    <ul class="pagination pagination-template d-flex justify-content-center">
                      {% if page_obj.has_previous %}
                      <li class="page-item"><a href="?page=1" class="page-link"> <i class="fa fa-angle-left" aria-hidden="true"></i><i class="fa fa-angle-left" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
                      <li class="page-item"><a href="?page={{ page_obj.previous_page_number }}" class="page-link"> <i class="fa fa-angle-left" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
                      {% endif %}

                      {% for num in page_obj.paginator.page_range %}
                      {% if page_obj.number == num %}
                      <li class="page-item"><a href="?page={{ num }}" class="page-link active">{{ num }}</a></li>
                      {% elif num > page_obj.number|add:'-3' and num < page_obj.number|add:'3' %}
                      <li class="page-item"><a href="?page={{ num }}" class="page-link">{{ num }}</a></li>
                      {% endif %}
                     {% endfor %}

                     {% if page_obj.has_next %}
                      <li class="page-item"><a href="?page={{ page_obj.next_page_number }}" class="page-link"> <i class="fa fa-angle-right" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
                      <li class="page-item"><a href="?page={{ page_obj.paginator.num_pages }}" class="page-link"><i class="fa fa-angle-right" aria-hidden="true"></i><i class="fa fa-angle-right" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
                      {% endif %}
                    </ul>
                  </nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

The return type from `filter` is a `QuerySet` (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/)

The Paginator documentation (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/paginator/#django.core.paginator.Paginator) says that it expects a list for its first argument.

The QuerySet documentation says that in order to force evaluation as a list, you can call `list()`

Thefore:

`Paginator(post.list(), 6)`

Comment: Adding .list() to post gave me an exception error. Exception Value: 
'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'list'

Comment: i have also tried adding the queryset into list(). like so: posts = list(post.filter(category=category).order_by('-id'))

Comment: Sorry, you're absolutely right @KaluPatrick; it should be `list(post)`; I misread the documentation. You said you tried that; did it give you an error?